# How to generate a new Component in Nativescript with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, command-line-interface, nativescript

I'm new to Nativescript and Angular and wonder how to generate a new Component. 
I've create a new Project with `tns create` and then choose Angular as Framework and a Template.
After playing around I want to add a new Component but don't know how. I've try to install `@nativescript/schematics` with npm and try `tns generate component ...` but then get this exception:

```
Error: Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
    at t.project (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:250:1038)
    at t._tryNext (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:30:1878)
    at t._next (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:30:1780)
    at t.next (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:16:1093)
    at e._subscribe (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:74:13873)
    at e._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:16:4641)
    at e.subscribe (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:16:4427)
    at e.call (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:30:1459)
    at e.subscribe (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:16:4299)
    at C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:145:10377
    at s (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:16:6063)
    at t._innerSub (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:30:2033)
    at t._tryNext (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:30:1957)
    at t._next (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:30:1780)
    at t.next (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics-executor\dist\index.js:16:1093)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nativescript\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:207:16)
```

Comment: If you are using VSCode then you could use this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joshdsommer.vscode-add-angular-native-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the [schematics documentation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics#generating-components-modules-directives-etc), try

```
ng g c component-name
```